# SQL Case Statement Setting as NULL for Some

Tags: mysql, sql, case

Hi I noticed that my SQL case statement is incorrect and is setting the field Age as NULL for ids 1-3. How would I stop this from happening?

Thanks

```
UPDATE table 
SET `Name` = CASE `id`
               WHEN 1 THEN 'Sam'  
               WHEN 2 THEN 'Adam'  
               WHEN 3 THEN 'James'  
               WHEN 4 THEN 'Chris'
             END, 
    `Age` = CASE `id` 
               WHEN 4 THEN '22'
            END  
WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `ELSE Age` to your case expression:

```
`Age` = CASE `id` WHEN 4 THEN '22' ELSE `Age` END
--                                 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

This causes the age to be set back to its original value.

The full query then looks like this:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `Name` = CASE `id`
                 WHEN 1 THEN 'Sam' 
                 WHEN 2 THEN 'Adam'
                 WHEN 3 THEN 'James'
                 WHEN 4 THEN 'Chris'
             END,
    `Age`  = CASE `id`
                 WHEN 4 THEN '22'
                 ELSE `Age`
             END
WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
UPDATE table 
SET `Name` = 
    CASE `id` 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Sam'  
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Adam'  
        WHEN 3 THEN 'James'  
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Chris'  
    END, 
    `Age` = 
    CASE `id` 
        WHEN 4 THEN '22' 
        ELSE Age 
    END  
WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Haven't tested this, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a WHEN... THEN for 1 - 3. Otherwise it won't assign anything. Or add an else.